# How can a Java enum value be used as a true Static Constant

Tags: java, oop, static, enums

Alrighty, so I did some research on constants and how they should be designed and used.  For my application, it made sense to have numerous enums that would group terms that are related to each other.

The idea being that as I develop web services with hundreds of parameters (many of which are used more than once) and methods, I could annotate using the values of the enums.  Before this, there was a huge, disgusting Constants file with redundant and unmaintained values.

So, here's an enum I'd like to use:

```
package com.company.ws.data.enums;

/** This {@link Enum} contains all web service methods that will be used. **/
public enum Methods {

    /** The name of the web service for looking up an account by account number. **/
    FIND_ACCOUNT_BY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER("accountByNumberRequest");

    /** The String value of the web service method name to be used in SOAP **/
    private String value;

    private Methods(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the String value of the web service method name to be used in
     *         SOAP
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

And here's a place I'd like to use it:

```
package com.company.ws.data.models;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.company.ws.data.enums.Methods;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = **Methods.FIND_ACCOUNT_BY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER**, namespace = "com.company.ws")
public class AccountByNumberRequest{
}
```

So, if I try the above, I get the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Methods to String` which makes perfect sense.  So, let's try accessing the actual value of the enum:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = **Methods.FIND_ACCOUNT_BY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER.getValue()**, namespace = "")
public class AccountByNumberRequest extends RequestByAccount {
}
```

Doing that, I get this error message: `The value for annotation attribute XmlRootElement.name must be a constant expression`.

So, can I use enums like I'm trying to?  Can they be used in place of true static constant values as defined in a final class?  Or am I in some weird compile-time state where the annotations are being evaluated before the enum itself is loaded and instantiated with its values? Guiding Resource: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=1

Comment: Enums /are/ constant, you don't do dynamic storage through them (unless you want to pass a number through that one constructor and do something with it, in which case, why are you using an enum?)

Comment: This may or may not solve your issue, but what happens if you change it to `private final String value;`, then call `Methods.FIND_ACCOUNT_BY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER.value`?

Comment: I can be rather puritan myself, but a 10+ line enum plus a method call because you don't like static finals seems a biiiiit over the top.

Comment: @Rogue, I'm not really trying to dynamically populate the enum values.  I'm initializing the enum one time and the values, once the enum is initialized, are unchangeable.  And again, I'm using an enum to list the values belonging to a group (e.g., web service methods available for consumption).  From different things I've read, this is the more correct approach to this issue; the other being a final class with all constants defined as `static final` objects.  Using an enum, I can now use its values in `switch` statements as well; it offers more flexibility and usability.

Comment: He wasn't suggesting you _were_ dynamically populating `enum` values; he was just saying that would be the only case in which an `enum` value would not be a constant expression.  In your case, it _is_ a constant expression, but the result of a method call (`getValue()`) is not.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that makes sense to me.  @pobrelkey was saying as much, too.  Forgive me for being dense, but what I'm hearing is that the way I'd like to utilize an enum is not possible then, eh?  They are not interchangeable with the usefulness of a `static final` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. The value of `Methods.getValue()` is not a constant expression according to the JLS, which is what the compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations don't get evaluated or instantiated.  They're just directives that tell the compiler to embed additional data (not code) into the compiled class, which you can later query using the reflection API.

As a consequence of this the only things that can be set as values of an annotation are constants - in other words, values that are known at compile time and can be reduced to something that can be placed in the class's constant pool: primitive values, strings, references to other classes, references to enum values, arrays of the above.

So you can't set an annotation value from a method call - their values can only be known once executed at runtime.  (Well, perhaps not if the method always returns the same value, but in the interest of simplifying the language and the compiler the Java spec doesn't require the compiler to be sophisticated enough to figure this out.)

Comment: What about [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) which annotations add code into your classes?

Comment: This is an example of one frequent use case for annotations: as a compiler directive.  The Lombok annotations tell the compiler to decorate/modify your class's compiled code in a certain manner.  But in general, you can't write an arbitrary annotation to extend your classes with code.

Comment: @pobrelkey, so if an annotation can only take a constant and you stated that enum values are constants, what's the deal here then?  Is that not what I'm using/doing?

Comment: Your first example (trying to assign a `String` annotation from a `Methods`) fails for obvious reasons.  Your second example fails because you're trying to assign an annotation (whose value has to be a constant known at compile time) from a method call (whose value can only be known at runtime). It doesn't matter that this method call is on an enum value - it's still a method call and will still fail.